# Overriding CSS onclick with while and setTimeOut

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to change/override the .left property of my css with javascript onclick. This I have managed to do, only I want the property to change in stages (every 1 sec) decrementing by 5em until it reaches 0em. Unfortunately, when I click on the ID to start the function, it just jumps from 30em to 0em. Instead of 30,25,20,15,10,5 etc every 1 sec. Any ideas? (No Jquery please!)

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("objection1").onclick = firstScroll;
}

function firstScroll(){

var content = document.getElementById("intB");
var thisNum = 30;
var em = "em";

function doScroll(){
    content.style.left = thisNum+em;
}

while(thisNum > 0){
    setTimeout(doScroll, 1000);
    thisNum -= 5;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is when you call the while loop, the next interval is not fired yet, but your `thisNum` is already set to 0 after finishing the loop. So when the `doScroll` is fired, `thisNum` is 0 already.

Try:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("objection1").onclick = firstScroll;
}

var thisNum = 30;
var em = "em";

function firstScroll(){
   setTimeout(doScroll, 1000);
}

function doScroll(){
    thisNum -= 5;
    var content = document.getElementById("intB");
    content.style.left = thisNum+em;
    if (thisNum > 0){
         setTimeout(doScroll, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change content.style.left = thisNum+em; to content.style.left = thisNum+"em"; otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: @jeff: the above code of OP already declares: `var em = "em";`

Comment: @Khanh-to - Thank you very much! It all makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're repeatedly decrementing thisNum in a while loop. setTimeout is a function which is called in one second, but the while loop keeps going. doScroll should be decrementing the em value, not a while loop outside. This uses setInterval instead of setTimeout, but either will do..

```
var intTimer;

function doScroll(){
    thisNum -= 5;
    content.style.left = thisNum+"em";

    if (thisNum <= 0){
        window.clearInterval(intTimer);
    }
}

intTimer = setInterval( doScroll, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you @vogomatix - I had to go with Khanh-to because although your answer worked, I only understood it after I had processed the answer from Khanh-to.

Comment: No problem - it's good practice to upvote answers that were constructive and accept the one you use in the end :-)